# Checkbox and label not properly aligning in different code the same is working separately

Tags: html, css

I have just started learning html and css3. trying to create a login page but when I am trying to add once check box its not inline with label. When I run the same code only for check box its inline. not able to understand what is the exact issue.

HTML Code is

```
<div class="checkbox1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb">
                <label for="cb">Stay signed in</label> 
</div>
```

CSS code is

```
#wrapper #subwrapper .checkbox1{
    display: inline-block;         
    float: left; 
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
}
```

When I include the same in my complete html code and css code the check box and label are not perfect.

Complete HTML code is.

```
<!doctype html>
<head>
    <title>Dchamps-Signin</title>
    <style> 
        body {
            background-image: url("bg_signin.jpg"); 
            background-repeat: no-repeat;
        }       
    </style>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="signin.css">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
            <div class="header">

            <div>
    </header>

    <div id="wrapper">  
        <div class="logo">
            <img src="Logo_FF.gif">
        </div>
        <div class="heading">
            Sign in to your account         
        </div>
        <div id="subwrapper">

            <div class="un">
                Username
            </div>

            <input type="text" size="60">

            <div class="pw">
                Password
            </div>

            <input type="text" size="60">

            <div class="signin">
            <button class="button">Sign in</button>
            </div>

            <div class="checkbox1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="cb">
                <label for="cb">Stay signed in</label>                  
            </div>

            <div class="needhelp">
                 Need Help?
            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

    <footer>
        <div class="footer">
                <ul>
                    <li>Help</li>
                    <li>Terms</li>
                    <li>CompanyInfo</li>                           
                </ul>
        </div>
    </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

and My complete CSS Code

```
.header {
width: 100%;
height: 50px;
margin-bottom: 25;
}
#wrapper{
 width: 800px;
 margin: 0 auto;
float: center;
text -align: center;
}
#wrapper .logo{
margin-top: 25px;
text-align: center;
}
#wrapper .heading{
padding-top: 20px;
font-size: 45px;
color: #e94324;
text-align: center;
}
#wrapper #subwrapper {
width: 400px;
margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrapper #subwrapper .un {
padding-top: 15px;
color: #f6ec28;
font-size: 25px;
float: left;
padding-left: 5px;
}
#wrapper #subwrapper .pw {
padding-top: 15px;
color: #f6ec28;
font-size: 25px;
float: left;
padding-left: 5px;
}
#wrapper #subwrapper input{
 padding-top: 5px;
background-color: transparent;
height: 50px;
}
#wrapper #subwrapper .signin{
padding-top: 15px;
color: #f6ec28;
font-size: 25px;
}
#wrapper #subwrapper .button{
background-color: #f26534;
height: 65px;
width: 380px;
font-size: 35px;
/*-moz-border-radius: 15px;
-webkit-border-radius: 15px;
border-radius: 15px;*/
color: #ffffff;
top: 55%;
}
#wrapper #subwrapper form {
}
#wrapper #subwrapper .checkbox1{
    display: inline-block;         
    float: left; 
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #ffffff;
    position: relative;
}
#wrapper #subwrapper .needhelp{
float: right;
color: #f6ec28;
padding-bottom: 80px;
}
.footer{
height: 20px;
clear: both;
border-top: 1px solid #254A73;
}
.footer ul li{
float: right;
display:inline-block;
margin-right: 20px;
color: #ffffff;
}
```

I am not sure why the check box is not in line.

Regards,
KJ

Comment: Hi Mikey, that is the problem I am facing. I am just a learner and try to create the page. Every thing else is as per my requirement only check box is not working properly. this is the output i am getting http://jsfiddle.net/n2b93zaz/. how can I identify which id or class is creating problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a fiddle with the fixed checkbox alignment issue, it is just a quick fix but you should try to think about your structure and how you style: http://jsfiddle.net/n2b93zaz/2/

```
#wrapper #subwrapper .checkbox1 {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
    font-size: 20px;
    color: #000000;
    position: relative;
}

/*Added this css rule to override the input properties set earlier*/

#wrapper #subwrapper .checkbox1 input{
    height:auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem this:

```
#wrapper #subwrapper input{
padding-top: 5px;
background-color: transparent;
height: 50px; //This is your problem. Change height to auto or without value.
}
```

Comment: Hi Stanislav, Thanks for the reply, it worked but changed my complete layout.